# xml encoding and jquery parsing

Tags: jquery, xml, encoding

Im having some trouble reading xml files using jquery that containts swedish chars (åäö) in my xml.

It doesnt matter if i use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

i will still get a parseerror in jquery. However, if i open the files in notepad++ and save with "utf-8 without BOM" it will work. But this is not an option, since i cant assume that all teh users will do that. How do i solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the parse-error you are receiving?

The most common issue with XML files not working correctly is caused by white space, so maybe worth checking this.

A useful URL is http://www.usingxml.com/Basics/XmlSpace

Thanks

Comment: I am trimming all the whitespaces already. Should i replace the ö ä å with the ascii code? The error that jquery throws is `DOM Exception: SYNTAX_ERR (12)`