# Error when parsing an XML file to DOM

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

I'm trying to parse an XML file using DocumentBuilderFactory as follows:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory ndsParserFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance( );
ndsParserFactory.setNamespaceAware( true );
DocumentBuilder ndsParser = ndsParserFactory.newDocumentBuilder( );
Document ndsDocument = ndsParser.parse( ndsFileInputStream );
```

where ndsFileInputStream is an InputStream wrapping the file containing the XML.

I get an exception when the file contains a Unicode character such as Δ.  When I strip out the line containing the offending character, the parsing works just fine.

The file contains the characteristic `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` header.

I'm wondering if I'm neglecting to configure the DocumentBuilderFactory (or DocumentBuilder) instance properly in order to handle the Δ character.

**Edit** (from comments):

Full disclosure: This is Android, and I'm including XML files (with an NDS file extension) as assets in my Android app. I access them via the AssetManager, which has a handy-dandy method for opening an asset file into an InputStream, which I then pass to the parse method of my DocumentBuilder. – d weld 16 hours ago

I noticed that the assets folder uses an encoding of CP1252 by default for its contents. So I changed that to UTF8. No luck. Then I removed the BOM from one of the NDS files (per link) and tried again. No luck. I'm thinking that the APK file (which is compressed like a ZIP file) is somehow mangling the non-ASCII XML. I think I'll have to resort to getting the NDS files onto the Android device by other means...

Comment: Have you checked that the file *actually contains* the right byte sequence for a [capital delta character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/394/index.htm)? Open the file in a hex editor, you should see a `0xCE 0x94` sequence. Do you?

Comment: Yes, I see 0xCE 0x94 (surrounded by 1-byte ASCII codes representing standard characters).

Comment: When you open the XML file with a different tool - your web browser, for example - does it load and display correctly? If it does, the file is fine and your Java set-up is wrong. Compare here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html, namely the third paragraph (*"If you omit the encoding identifier..."*).

Comment: Namely, you should use the [`parse(java.io.File f)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.io.File)) of your `DocumentBuilder` instance, instead of passing a `FileInputStream`. The `DocumentBuilder` will analyze and honor the XML declaration automatically.

Comment: It should Just Work. Can you post the full code (from creating the `File` to calling the `parse(InputStream)` method), the sample XML and the tip of the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: @Tomalak - Using parse(File) is more direct, but the OP is not using Readers here, so there is no conversion from bytes to characters before getting to the parser. There should be no problem, he is sticking to streams.

Comment: Getting back to your previous comment:  Yes, I can read the XML by other means.  Full disclosure:  This is Android, and I'm including XML files (with an NDS file extension) as assets in my Android app.  I access them via the AssetManager, which has a handy-dandy method for opening an asset file into an InputStream, which I then pass to the parse method of my DocumentBuilder.

Comment: I noticed that the assets folder uses an encoding of CP1252 by default for its contents.  So I changed that to UTF8.  No luck.  Then I removed the BOM from one of the NDS files (per [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7846404/1408802)) and tried again.  No luck.  I'm thinking that the APK file (which is compressed like a ZIP file) is somehow mangling the non-ASCII XML.  I think I'll have to resort to getting the NDS files onto the Android device by other means...

Comment: I've added your additional info and re-tagged this question as android related, you might get a better response from an android expert. If you want good answers, you've got to write good questions, and particularly include as much detail as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the file is really written as UTF-8? Obviously you can open it in some editor and it shows the text correctly, but it could just be making a good guess as the encoding.

The other thing to remember is *all* the characters are Unicode in UTF-8 - the parser is just choking when it hits a byte sequence that isn't valid in the declared encoding. UTF-8 is a very forgiving encoding to use as any character in the 7-bit ASCII set is encoded as if it is plain ASCII, and a lot of XML is made up of nothing but plain ASCII characters. This then catches people out when something non-ASCII comes up and suddenly defects in the text encoding paths through a system become apparent.

You could try editing the XML declaration and see if it parses ok under another character encoding; [8859-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7) contains the Δ symbol - could it be encoded in that?

Also, what is the exception?

Comment: It's a DOMException with a detailMessage of the element name that it barfed on ("RΔaEnabled").