# XML parsing error: UTF-8

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I'm attempting to read in as data an XML file (with an "NDS" extension) into my Android app.  I'm choosing to go the DOM DocumentBuilder route, calling its parse method.

The problem is the presence of a non-ASCII delta (Δ) character in one of the node names.  This causes the parsing operation to fail with a DOMException.  When I strip out the offending line, it works.

The XML file itself I create under Windows using .NET library methods, and it has a header of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.  (I also notice that this header has the 3-byte BOM in front.)

The XML hierarchy around the offending line looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NDS SoftwareIdentity="MicroAnalyzer 2000" SoftwareVersion="3.5.8" WindowsVersion="Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3" CLRVersion="2.0.50727.3615" MachineName="SYSTEM2000_3033" MachineDescription="" DataSource="System2000_3033\SQLEXPRESS" Date="3/31/2012" Time="11:15 AM">
    <ASME_B46_1_2002DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ASME_B46_1_2002DataSet.xsd">
        <ASME_B46_1_2002RoughnessInstanceTable>
            <InstanceAppendixId>-1</InstanceAppendixId>
            <RΔaEnabled>false</RΔaEnabled>
        </ASME_B46_1_2002RoughnessInstanceTable>
    </ASME_B46_1_2002DataSet>
</NDS>
```

You would think that the delta character would be acceptable under UTF-8, and in fact this XML is interpreted properly by Internet Explorer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when parsing an XML file to DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692693/error-when-parsing-an-xml-file-to-dom)

Answer (score 1):

Reading http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar

```
[4]     NameStartChar      ::=      ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]


[4a]    NameChar       ::=      NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
```

There are unicode characters which are valid in XML 1.0, but not all. You character (#x394) is a valid NameStartChar as is in the range [#x37F-#x1FFF].

Answer (score -1):

I believe that XML 1.0 requires element and attribute names to contain only ASCII characters (and some non-printing ASCII-characters are forbidden). Declaring UTF-8 encoding allows non-ASCII characters to appear in the *values* of elements and attributes.

XML 1.1 relaxed this to allow Unicode, non-ASCII characters in elements and attribute names.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "XML 1.0 (Fifth Edition) and XML 1.1 support the direct use of almost any Unicode character in element names, attributes, comments, character data, and processing instructions"

Comment: The presence of a 2-byte UTF-8 code in the element name certainly appears to be the problem.  Can't say for certain what edition of XML 1.0 is being applied by the org.w3c.dom DocumentBuilder I'm using.