# Android dom parser - illegal characters exception

Tags: android, utf-8, domparser

I need to parse a xml document in my Android application and I'm using Dom parser. Encoding in my xml file is set to UTF-8. The code I'm using for parsing is as follows:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputStream inStream = getAssets().open("words.xml");
    InputSource inSource = new InputSource(inStream);
    inSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    Document doc = db.parse(inSource);
```

But the problem is that I get an illegal character exception. The node which is problematic has the following structure:

```
    <obriši>
        <item>obriši</item>
        <item>ukloni</item>
    </obriši>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What happens if you change the input tags to `<obrisi>...</obrisi>`? Not sure, but I think the tag names have to be ASCII. UTF-8 for tag content should be ok.

Comment: @Axel That was the problem. But according to xml recommendation it shouldn't be the problem. But according to this SO question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692693/error-when-parsing-an-xml-file-to-dom) there is some strange behaviour in Android. At the end I changed structure of my xml file and made a new parser

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
inSource.setEncoding("windows-1251");
```